# Run java code every X seconds, but if the code works don't wait TimeUnit.sleep

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to run a script sh every 10 minutes, the script aim is to setup an application on server.
So I have defined a method that test if the application is deployed successfully on server.

My code works as follows : run the script sh that deploy application on server, wait for 10 minutes, test deployment on server by calling a method testDeployment() that returns a boolean.

```
for (int i=0; i<=x;i++) {
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start "+"\\script.sh");
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(300);
testDeploy=testDep.testDeployment();
}
```

But what I need is to test the deployment each 20 seconds, if the application is successfully deployed, I won't have to wait for 10 minutes.

```
do {            
testDeploy=testDep.testDeployment();
}while(testDeploy==false&& "while time is inferior than 10 minutes");
```

Any help please

Comment: The `exec` call returns a `Process` object which you can use to wait for the completion and test the return status. Use that, instead of making guesswork about how many minutes it takes. It’s also not clear why you are testing when the test result has no consequences; when the test succeeds, you will test again, when the test fails, you will also test again, but with a different delay.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
Instant start = Instant.now();

boolean testDeploy = false;

do {
     // ...
     testDeploy = testDep.testDeployment();
} while (!testDeploy && Duration.between(start, Instant.now()).toMinutes() < 10);
```